# Promise in setTimeOut loop: return resolve() or if-else

Tags: loops, promise, return

TL;DR: It appears Promise's `resolve()` returns, which in a looping function causes the promise to keep running. What's the proper way to call resolve() for looping promises?

Details:
I built a setTimeOut loop for animation purposes which would run for a number of times, then exit the loop.

Simply calling `resolve` when done did not work: it did resolve the promise but then kept running.

```
function timeoutLoop (fcn, steps = -1, time = 0) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    function timeoutStep () {
      if (steps-- === 0) resolve() // steps will be -1
      fcn()
      setTimeout(timeoutStep, time)
      console.log(steps)
    }
    timeoutStep()
  })
}
timeoutLoop(() => {}, 10).then(() => console.log('done'))
```

Two fixes worked: use an `if-else` or have the if use `return resolve()`

Use if-else

```
  if (steps-- === 0) {
    resolve() // steps will be -1
  } else {
    fcn()
    setTimeout(timeoutStep, time)
    console.log(steps)
  }
```

return the resolve() call

```
if (steps-- === 0) return resolve() // steps will be -1
```

My concern is that, even if both "work", there may be side effects I don't understand such as the call-stack retaining the call frame of the Promise body.

What's the best practice in this case?

Edit: The answer @Bergi gave, using async functions, is clearly the right philosophy. I did make one minor change, using a while loop rather than recursion:

`function timeoutPromise( ms = 1000) {
  return new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, ms) })
}
async function timeoutLoop (fcn, steps = -1, time = 0) {
  while (steps-- !== 0) {  // Note decr occurs *after* comparison
    fcn()
    await timeoutPromise(time)
  }
}
timeoutLoop(() => {}, 10, 1000).then(() => console.log('done'))`

Comment: BTW: Yes, if called with a negative steps param, it will loop continuously. This is on purpose .. I'm interested here in the stopping case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resolve()` is not syntax, it does not stop execution of anything like a `return` statement does. You have to explicitly *not* call `setTimeout` again to prevent it from occurring. Both early return and `else` work fine for you there.

> What's the best practice in this case?

Not to do any complicated stuff in non-promise asynchronous callbacks.

Promisify on the lowest possibly level - the `setTimeout` function and only that. Write your program logic with promises.

```
function delay(t) {
  return new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, t); });
}
async function timeoutLoop (fcn, steps = -1, time = 0) {
  if (steps !== 0) {
    fcn()
    console.log(steps);
    await delay(time)
    return timeoutLoop(fcn, steps-1, time);
  }
}
```

Comment: Superb! Using an async function, which also returns a promise, is definitely a winner. I did use a while loop rather than calling the fcn. And I already had a timeoutPromise in the code! Sweet!