# Bluebird promise failing to short circuit on reject

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

Maybe I just don't understand promises but I've used this pattern before and never had issues. Using bluebird within node.

I have this function which is getting hit:

```
function getStores() { 
    return new Bluebird((resolve, reject) => {
        return Api.Util.findNearbyStores(Address,(stores) => {
             if (!stores.result) {                 
                 console.log('one')
                 reject('no response');
                 console.log('two')
             }

             const status = stores.results.status
        })
    })
}
```

then hits both of my logs, continues past the if and throws

```
 'one'
 'two'
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Status' of undefined
```

Basically it keeps going right past the resolve.

My impression was the promise should immediately short circuit on reject and pass the rejection through as the resolution to the promise. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: reject doesn't exit function, add a return in the if, also, you don't use resolve so you will never get a result from getStores()

Comment: You are never calling  `resolve`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are misunderstanding this. `reject(…)` is not syntax (just like [`resolve(…)` isn't either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49015388/1048572)) and does not act like a `return` statement that exits the function. It's just a normal function call that returns `undefined`.

You should be using

```
if (!stores.result) reject(new Error('no response'));
else resolve(stores.results.status);
```

The "short-circuiting" behaviour of rejections is attributed to promise chains. When you have

```
getStores().then(…).then(…).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

then a rejection of the promise returned by `getStores()` will immediately reject all the promises in the chain and trigger the `catch` handler, ignoring the callbacks passed to `then`.